# Unable to enter gnome session - configuration GNOME power manager failed to install

Tags: 10.10, login-screen, gnome-power-manager

When I enter the password to login into the gnome session, it says the configuration for gnome-power manager installation failed and when I enter the password I get logged out automatically, to the login screen, what shall I do now?

Update:

this happens because lack of freespace in the partition in which your GNU Linux is installed, delete some files and you are gud to go

Answer (score 1):

Edited (and expanded based on comments) as a part of clean-up.

This is a typically problem of not enough space left on your root partition.

You can make space with `sudo apt-get clean`, enlarging your partition size with gparted, or removing unnecessary files.

In this case , pahnin resolved the issue by removing a large iso (see comments).

Regards,

Ilias el Matani

Comment: nopes its because of an iso file thanx btw

Comment: @pahnin answer your own question upbote it

Comment: @amit kk did that THNX

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting a 'safe mode' session from the login screen (the GDM chooser).  If that also fails, select the 'Recovery Console' option.   This will launch just single (xterm) terminal session without Gnome.  If that's necessary, view the contents of the .xsession-errors file.  It should give you a more specific reason for the failure.

You might make sure your filesystem has free space -- use `df -h` . Depending on your partition scheme, you should at least have room on your `/` filesystem.

If you do get a command line and it's still not obvious what the problem is, you might start with running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gnome-power-manager` from the command line.

Comment: I have got support from a friend of me to check if free space available in root partition, it sorted out the problem, anyway, thanx for the info. since there is no free space left on the drive, may be it has to create config files

Comment: I've never thought to look at exactly what files are created during a login session (usually something else fails as well in a case like this), but it's good to know this fixed your problem.